# how to hide browser url parameter angular2 routing

Tags: angular, routes

how to hide browser url parameter angular2 routing?
I have the following problem:

http://localhost:4200/product-detail/590f643acaa7dca998c2e5bd

I need to hide the parameter in the URL and get:

http://localhost:4200/product-detail/

The route is defined by the following code:

app.routing.ts:

```
 export const AppRoutes: any = [
 .....
 { path: "product-detail/:id", component: ProductDetailComponent }
 .....
 ];
```

ProductDetail.ts

```
  this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
    this.id = params['id'];
  })
```

Comment: You could store the params in a global service.

Comment: Using a route configuration like this you won't be able to. Ploppy has given the right solution, global service and BehaviorSubject is probably what you'll want to use.

Answer (score 2):

When navigating to the desired route, you could use `skipLocationChange`:

`this.router.navigate(['/product-detail'], { queryParams: this.id, skipLocationChange: true});`

Comment: This doesn't hide parameter values

Comment: Works perfect for Angular 8 , Thank You